# Can I get an AST representation of what was passed to my python function at runtime?

Tags: python, abstract-syntax-tree

At runtime, can I get an AST representation of an expression that was passed to my python function, either within the function or at the place where the function is called? That is, can I do something like:

```
def myFunc(cond):
  ast = give_me_ast(cond)

myFunc(1 > 0)
```

or

```
myFunc(give_me_ast(1 > 0))
```

Without forcing the user to make the condition a string?

Comment: No. It'd be easy to do that in something like R, but Python parameter passing passes objects, not expressions. At best, you could use `inspect` to make a kludgy, unreliable guess for what the expression was.

Comment: Python runs the `1>0` expression before passing it to the function.  So the expression is not passed, just the result (in this case a boolean `True`).

Comment: For debug purpose, which may not match your needs, you can put a breakpoint into the function, go up one level in the call stack, and see where you were called from and with what arguments...

Answer (score 0):

With the [inspect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html#the-interpreter-stack) library, you can retrace the call stack and reconstruct the the source code *string* (not the code *object*). From there you can feed it to [ast](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html).parse function.

The tricky thing is that a function call can span multiple lines, which makes the code below rather complex.

Note that this will only work if no extra function calls come in between.

In case you have an `arg = 1 > 0`, and then `my_func(arg)`, you wouldn't be able to see the *runtime* contents of `arg` in the parsed ast. You'd get an `ast.Name('arg', ast.Load())` expr, instead.

```py
import ast
import inspect


def get_outer_source_code(*, max_lines: int = 80):
    frame = inspect.currentframe()
    caller_stack = inspect.getouterframes(frame, max_lines)

    # function name of the
    func_name: str = caller_stack[1].function
    if func_name == '<module>':
        raise TypeError(
            'get_outer_source_code() must be called directly from a function'
        )

    caller_frameinfo = caller_stack[2]

    # figure out the slice of relevant lines
    line_i = caller_frameinfo.index
    source_pos_info = caller_frameinfo.positions
    line_n = source_pos_info.end_lineno - source_pos_info.lineno + 1

    source_lines = caller_frameinfo.code_context[line_i: line_i + line_n]
    assert source_lines[0].lstrip().startswith(func_name)
    assert ')' in source_lines[-1]  # .endswiith fails for trailing comments

    source_code = ''.join(source_lines).strip()
    assert source_code.startswith(func_name), source_code

    return source_code


def my_func(*args):
    source_code = get_outer_source_code()
    print(source_code)
    print()

    expr = ast.parse(source_code, mode='eval').body
    print(ast.dump(expr, indent=4))
```

~ *elsewhere* ~

```
my_func(
    # this is the first arg,
    1 > -1,
    # this is the second arg,
    # ... and it is optional
    # ...
    # ok, bye

    'spam',
    # 'ham',
    # 'eggs',
)
# don't notice me senpai
```

which prints

```
my_func(
    # this is the first arg,
    1 > -1,
    # this is the second arg,
    # ... and it is optional
    # ...
    # ok, bye

    'spam',
    # 'ham',
    # 'eggs',
)

Call(
    func=Name(id='my_func', ctx=Load()),
    args=[
        Compare(
            left=Constant(value=1),
            ops=[
                Gt()],
            comparators=[
                UnaryOp(
                    op=USub(),
                    operand=Constant(value=1))]),
        Constant(value='spam')],
    keywords=[])
```

This is **very** hacky. So aside from it being a <strike>cool</strike> party-trick, I wouldn't recommend using this in any project...

Comment: I think you meant `return source_code.lstrip()` at the end of `get_outer_source_code`. But you should also mention that it only works if the source file exists and has not been modified since it was imported.

Comment: @rici The `rstrip()` is for removing the trailing newline characters. The assertions in place make sure that this will fail fast if the source code has been edited in the meantime. There are many many more thing that can go wrong here, but I didn't want to overcomplicate things; hence the label of "hacky" ;)

Comment: ok, but you need to remove the leading spaces as well. When I tried it, the trailing return wasn't a problem, but the indent caused it to fail. (The call to `my_func` was indented because it was insideca function.)

Comment: @rici You're right, I've changed `.rstrip` to `.strip`